# card-columns class is missing in bootstrap 5.0 ? does bootstrap provide any alternative in addition to using css media queries and flex column?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-5

I didn't find card-columns class in bootstrap 5.0, and there is no mention of it or its alternative in [Bootstrap 5.0 docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/card/#card-layout). Its there in
[Bootstarp 4.6 docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/components/card/#card-columns).

I know we can use css media queries along with flex column, but in my case its getting too complex due to dynamic addition of cards.

So curious to know is there any bootstrap way to implement card-columns functionality in bootstrap 5.0 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [explained in the Bootstrap 5 docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/migration/#card), card-columns were dropped in favor of [Masonry](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/card/#masonry).

> "In v4 we used a CSS-only technique to mimic the behavior of
> Masonry-like columns, but this technique came with lots of unpleasant
> side effects. If you want to have this type of layout in v5, you can
> just make use of Masonry plugin. Masonry is not included in
> Bootstrap..."

[Bootstrap 5 Masonry Demo](https://codeply.com/p/yrjCBwUeKR)

---

Related: [Bootstrap 5 layout for different sizes cards - like Pinterest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65468063/bootstrap-5-layout-for-different-sizes-cards-like-pinterest)